# Strange method result using Math.round

Tags: javascript, methods, return

When this method is called with 
    knownScore = 70, 
    newScore = 70, 
    depth = 1,
it returns 3535 !!!!!
How is this possible?

```
this.weightedAvg = function(depth, knownScore, newScore) {
   if ((knownScore > 100) || (knownScore < -100)) return newScore;
   else return Math.round((depth*knownScore + newScore)/(depth + 1));
};
```

When called with values 35, 70, 2, it returns 2357!
Any help please?

Comment: returns 70 for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tjht7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse your var to number like this:

```
var number1 = Number(n);
```

You are passing string so he do "2" + "35" + "70" instead of 2 + 35 + 70 !

Comment: Thanks! Did that elsewhere to ensure that the passed parameter is number.

Answer (score 3):

The value of newScore you're passing to the function is a string. You should make sure they are all numbers. This code will work (notice the + sign that converts newScore to a number):

```
this.weightedAvg = function(depth, knownScore, newScore) {
    if ((knownScore > 100) || (knownScore < -100)) return newScore;
    else return Math.round((depth*knownScore + +newScore)/(depth + 1));
};
```

More details:

```
70 + '70' // this is string concatenation instead of addition, results in 7070
```

The result is converted to a number when it is divided by 2:

```
'7070'/2 // converts to number, resulting in 3535
```

Comment: Wonder can't `depth` be a number as well.

Comment: @raina77ow The results are consistent with just newScore (and possibly knownScore) being strings instead of numbers. If depth was a string as well, the division would result in a different number than 3535.